# Trying to install the latest Pytorch (1.13.1) instead installs 1.11.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm trying to install the latest Pytorch version, but it keeps trying to instead install 1.11.0. I'm on Windows 10 running Python 3.10.8, and I have CUDA 11.6 installed.

I'm running the following command:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

Even if I give it the flag --no-cache-dir, it proceeds to download 1.11.0 anyways. Running

```
pip install torch==1.13.1
```

Installs the CPU version. Any way that I can download the specific module directly and install it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I ran the following command to specifically install the version I wanted:

```
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116/torch-1.13.1%2Bcu116-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

You can find all the available wheels [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html). If you get involving "UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension", make sure you also install Torchvision **AT THE SAME TIME** as PyTorch.